# jQuery: scroll to the top of a div that has overflow: scroll;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/lalka/full/qOQxeq/)

I need on to scroll to the top of a div that has a fixed `height` and `overflow: scroll;`.

> JavaScript

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var $target = $('aside div:first-child');
  var scrTop = Math.abs($target.offset().top);
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: scrTop
    }, 400);
  console.log($target.offset().top)
});
```

The issue is that `console.log()` returns negative integer of the`offset.top` method, which should not happen in normal circumstances.

I tried different approaches but couldn't find a way.

Is that even possible?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Scroll to the bottom of the **pink** `div` with **green** `divs` inside.
2. Click the `button`
3. Open Dev Tools and see what `console.log();` returns
4. And the scroll to the top of the green `div` doesn't happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should read more about the offset function. It returns negative values whenever the first element in the set off matched elements is scrolled to a position above the top of the document.

Comment: possibly because you're animating the scrolling action on `html, body` as a whole rather than the `$target`

Comment: I've forked and updated your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbmxQY), this is working fine.

Comment: @iam-decoder lol thank you im such a donkey XD

Comment: @iam-decoder compose an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You want to use position(), but you also want to account for the fact that this will also return negative values in some cases.

Comment: @MjrKusanagi she used `Math.abs()` to get around the fact that it can return a negative value sometimes

Comment: @iam-decoder I really don't agree that abs is a correct way to handle negative values of position or offset. I would instead recommend  adding position.top value to the value of scrollTop of the offset parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forked an updated your codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbmxQY)

you were getting the `scrTop` value incorrectly and you were scrolling the entire html document (which didn't have a scroll)

### codepen JS

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var $target = $('aside');
  var scrTop = Math.abs($target.offset().top);
  $target.animate({
      scrollTop: scrTop
    }, 400);
  console.log(scrTop)
});
```

Comment: This example arbitrarily scrolls target's internal scroll to a value based on target's offset within the document. You are using offset and scrollTop in a way that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

just an idea,

```
$parentDiv.scrollTop($parentDiv.scrollTop() + $innerListItem.position().top);
```